# Trying to create a solution with a monogame project and a class library, and it won't let me add a reference between them

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

I wrote a game in XNA a while ago, it just has two projects - a game, and a library. It worked fine, and now I am porting it to Monogame.

I have created a MonoGame Game project, and a Class Library, and put all of the files from my old XNA project into them. The Class Library builds with no problems or errors. However, it won't let me add a reference to it from my other (game) project.

It just says "Unable to add a reference to [MyLibrary]"

I read something about it possibly being because they target different frameworks - one targets .net and one targets ".net CORE" but I don't know if this is the case, or how to fix it.

Can anyone advise me on what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably right about the framework targeting issues.

There are a few ways to deal with this, the first is to try and change you're library to a Portable Class Library. They are designed to be able to target different frameworks including the different frameworks MonoGame supports.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/gg597391.aspx

The downside of portable class libraries is that they only support a subset of the full .NET framework. If that's the case you'll want to try and change you're library into a Mono for Android Library project (or whatever framework you're targeting).

If you want to build for multiple target frameworks and need to minimize the amount of duplicate code in each project I think your best bet is to add the files as 'links' to each projects. It adds a bit of maintenance but allows you to edit a file in one project and have the change made across all projects.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I avoid the Portable Class Library both for the reasons that @craftworkgames specifies, and also from my own experience of developing a Windows 8 App - they just cause you hassle. While it's good from a design principle to separate your classes into a library of their own, I would just add them all to your development project (unless you're writing an API that you want the world to be able to use?)